.Net Maui Build Failing IOS
Title: Unable to Build .NET MAUI App for iOS: MessagingRemoteException and ArgumentNullException
I'm encountering an issue while trying to build my .NET MAUI app for iOS. This is the error message I receive:
Error (active) MessagingRemoteException: An error occurred on client Build1808316 while executing a reply for topic xvs/build/18.0.8316/execute-task/{AppName}/312865c002fWriteAppManifest
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path2
    GolfDart2.0 (net8.0-ios)    C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.0_18.0\18.0.8316\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets  643

What I’ve Tried:

Checked my App Manifest file:

Verified its existence and content. It seems fine, but I'm not sure if there’s a specific issue with the path or structure.


Reviewed my project settings:

Ensured all necessary configurations for iOS are included in my .csproj file. My project is configured for multiple platforms (Android, iOS, MacCatalyst, Windows) with custom assets, splash screens, and fonts.


Updated dependencies:

Verified that I am using the latest versions of the .NET SDK and the required packages (CommunityToolkit.Maui, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Plugin.Maui.Audio, etc.).


Environment setup:

I'm using a locked Mac in the cloud to build the app and have successfully set up all necessary certificates for iOS deployment. However, due to the locked environment, I have limited ability to directly clear caches or modify file permissions.


Verified build tools:

Confirmed that Xcode 16 and the .NET 8.0 iOS SDK are installed and compatible.



Despite these steps, I continue to encounter the error.
Questions:

Has anyone come across this specific error before? If so, how did you resolve it?
Is there a known issue with the Xamarin.Shared.targets file in this context, or any workarounds I should try?

Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.


You can check this thread about Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(366,3) MessagingRemoteException, AggregateException.
